# JavaScript/ASPX remove url string

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I have aspx project which is basic search by the text box value. The value I get from the url which looks like this:

```
/default.aspx?V1A%202B3
```

I use my JavaScript code to get the string and set it as text box value for asp to proceed:

```
<script>
var url = window.location.href;
    if((url).indexOf('?') != -1) {
        var queryString = (url).substr((url).indexOf('?') + 1); 
        var str1 = queryString.replace(/%20/g, ' ');
        var str2 = str1.replace('+', ' ');
        document.getElementById("TextBox1").value = str2;   
        if (typeof (history.pushState) != "undefined") {
        var obj = { Url: 'Default.aspx' };
        history.pushState(obj, obj.Title, obj.Url);
    } 
    }
</script>
```

so from here I get nice plain value "V1A 2B3" which I use for my search. It works but if I enter the search string by hand into text box, the url still has the old string, as well as text box after search button is clicked. Is there any way to fix it? I tried to remove it with `history.pushState`. It is not show in url bar but still is as text box value. My search box for asp:

```
 <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Go" onclick="Button1_Click"  />
```

Comment: Move your string manipulation from javascript/client side to C#/server side

Comment: Im not C# programmer so thats why i did on client side. Can you help me here?

Answer (score 0):

So I used Shannon`s answer and made it work on the server side:

```
string v = Request.QueryString["code"];
                if (v != null)
                        {
                        TextBox1.Text = v;
                        }
```

Now the url looks like this: `default.aspx?code=1v5a1c`